# Comparing 2 double epochs in java

Tags: java

If I am saving two epochs as a double value can I use a greater than or less than sign to deduce accurately that one is before in time than the other ?

Comment: Sure, just compare them as you would any other doubles. Of course, the usual warnings about floating-point precision apply. Why not use longs of millis-since-epoch, which is very standard?

Comment: Did you give it a go with several test cases?

Comment: If the doubles store the time in millis you won't lose an precision though using a `long` as `System.currentTimeMillis()` does would be a more obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Documentation:

> The epoch-seconds are measured from the standard Java epoch of
>   1970-01-01T00:00:00Z where instants after the epoch have positive
>   values, and earlier instants have negative values. For both the
>   epoch-second and nanosecond parts, a larger value is always later on
>   the time-line than a smaller value.

So, to answer your question: **yes**  you can compare them as doubles.